# Python - Count the number of dictionary keys with values that match a certain lookup string

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary as follows:

```
Key       Value
5zd {'status': 'Outofservice', 'date': '201505'}
8km {'status': 'Peaking', 'date': '201505'}
erg {'status': 'Outofservice', 'date': '201505'}
xrg {'status': 'Booming', 'date': '201505', 'rate': 18.691588785046733, 'mean': 4}
86e {'status': 'Constant', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -9.6810933940774486, 'mean': -17}
4ld {'status': 'Constant', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -4.7619047619047619, 'mean': -1}
zzz {'status': 'Dropping', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -67.34693877551021, 'mean': -11}
```

I would like to count the number of keys whose value contains the words 'Booming', 'Outofservice', 'Peaking', 'Constant' and 'Dropping' respectively. Resultant output should be:

```
date    Booming    OutofService    Peaking    Constant    Dropping
201505  1          2               1          2           1
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try and what was the result?

Comment: Iterate through the (key, value) pairs, if the value contains a keyword, increment a counter.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I tried this: for key in dict.keys():
    if "Constant" in dict[key]:
        constantcount +=1

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 However, my variable constantcount contains 0 as the value after execution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count the frequency by extracting the relevant data, storing it to a list and then passing the list to [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which returns a `Counter` object representing the frequency of each element occurred in the given list.

```
import collections

d = {'5zd': {'status': 'Outofservice', 'date': '201505'},
     '8km': {'status': 'Peaking', 'date': '201505'},
     'erg': {'status': 'Outofservice', 'date': '201505'},
     'xrg': {'status': 'Booming', 'date': '201505', 'rate': 18.691588785046733, 'mean': 4},
     '86e': {'status': 'Constant', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -9.6810933940774486, 'mean': -17},
     '4ld': {'status': 'Constant', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -4.7619047619047619, 'mean': -1},
     'zzz': {'status': 'Dropping', 'date': '201505', 'rate': -67.34693877551021, 'mean': -11}}

lst = [value["status"] for value in d.values()]

print collections.Counter(lst)
>>> Counter({'Outofservice': 2, 'Constant': 2, 'Peaking': 1, 'Booming': 1, 'Dropping': 1})

counter_obj = collections.Counter(lst)
for i in counter_obj:
    print i, counter_obj[i]
>>> Peaking 1
    Outofservice 2
    Booming 1
    Dropping 1
    Constant 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know of any way that I can get rid of the 'Counter' substring in the resultant output - Counter({'Outofservice': 2, 'Constant': 2, 'Peaking': 1, 'Booming': 1, 'Dropping': 1})

Comment: Actually, I found how to do that. You need to do: collections.Counter(lst).most_common(10)